# Ejabberd chat service integration

Tags: python, xmpp, chat, ejabberd

I have installed ejabberd and got it to work on my Macbook.

I have a site written in python, in which i would like to integrate the chat feature which is backed by the ejabberd server.
The user should be able to register for chat from the website and be able to send messages through website. 
What is a good way to do this ? Using hooks or res_apis or any better solution ?

Answer (score 0):

I propose you to use [Converse.js](http://conversejs.org). Its building the UI on its own and its really easy to integrate it in your website. Only the registration should be made by you. Everything else is already there. Hope this works for you! Good luck.